# How to find the accumulated time between two

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a two datatables like below:

DT1

```
  id            start_time             end_time
 604        2017-08-10 18:44:14    2017-08-11 19:33:17
 604        2017-08-10 20:38:20    2017-08-11 20:44:44
 604        2017-08-10 20:54:26    2017-08-11 20:58:48
 604        2017-08-10 21:35:50    2017-08-11 22:03:14
 604        2017-08-10 22:05:42    2017-08-11 22:17:12
```

.......

DT2

```
 id             t1                            t2
 604        2017-08-10 18:40:14    2017-08-11 18:44:14
 604        2017-08-10 18:44:14    2017-08-11 18:47:14
 604        2017-08-10 19:44:14    2017-08-11 19:47:14
 604        2017-08-10 20:30:14    2017-08-11 20:42:20
 604        2017-08-10 21:44:14    2017-08-11 21:49:14
 604        2017-08-10 22:44:14    2017-08-11 22:48:14
```

......

From these two I want to identify the accumulation of the DT2 rows lying inbetween the range of DT!.For example row 1 is starting from `2017-08-10 18:44:14 to 2017-08-11 19:33:17` So I want to take the accumulation of time in DT between that period and attach as column fro eah row  in DT1
for example the first row would be like

```
   id            start_time             end_time           durationFromDT2
   604        2017-08-10 18:44:14    2017-08-11 19:33:17       420
   604        2017-08-10 20:38:20    2017-08-11 20:44:44       240
```

The 420 is because of `(2017-08-11 18:44:14-2017-08-10 18:40:14)+(2017-08-11 18:47:14-2017-08-10 18:44:14)` .If there are no occurences in DT2 in the time period then I would like it to be 0.Like wise I have to group by many id's as well.

The 240 because of the time is `(2017-08-11 20:42:20-2017-08-10 20:38:20)`

So it's basically the coverage of DT2 for DT1 time period
I tried looping through the rows but did not go well.Instead I am looking for any **dplyr** or **data table** solutions.Because looping was not working well

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think that what you are looking for are grep and gsub family of functions

Comment: i don't think so grep is used to match patterns right  if i am not wrong.but here I have to iterate through the DT2 and then associate with DT1

Comment: how do you handle cases when `end_time` lies between `t1` and `t2` of the same row?

Comment: I am not sure what you are refering to.I want the sum t1 and t2 occurences in between the start_time and end_time period.Could you give an example what are u refering to if you don't mind

Comment: Assuming you are only looking for dplyr solutions, feel free to remove the [tag: datatable] tag. Also, can you provide a small, copy/pastable example, the solution to it and the code you've tried so far?

Comment: No data table solution is also ok. Ok i will update

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Is this more clear?

Comment: 1) Are the end dates all meant to fall on 2017-08-10 (and not 2017-08-11)? making the units for `durationFromDT2` to be seconds?
2) Re: `The 420 is because of (2017-08-11 18:44:14-2017-08-10 18:40:14)+(2017-08-11 18:47:14-2017-08-10 18:44:14)` - you include time that is not between the start and end time of DT1. If the conditions are that the time must be between DT1 times, wouldn't the first row add up to 180 seconds instead? (as the only DT2 record within the DT1 limits is the 18:44 to 18:47 record?)

Comment: I second @JensLeerssen the dates are obviously should from the same day in both tables in order to be in such small distances from each other. And for the first row in `DT1` only the second row in `DT2` falls in it's interval, while no row in `DT2` falls in the interval of the second row in `DT1`. In short you really need to fix your example. Other than that, assuming all the date columns are of correct format, a data.table solution would be among these lines `DT2[DT1, sum(difftime(t2, start_time, units = "secs"), na.rm = TRUE), on = .(id, t1 >= start_time, t2 <= end_time), by = .EACHI]`

Comment: @JensLeerssen Sorry for late.the  end dates can fall on different dates.This has some problem when i run it in my whole data . The only line in DT2 for a day is like `3
2017-09-11 07:43:54
2017-09-11 07:47:26
` Then in my DT1 the record is like  `3
2017-09-11 18:44:14
2017-09-11 19:33:17
` But then the durationFromDT2 =1458 which twofold of the end_time-start_time.where I have no stretch in between.Could you advise on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the rectifications suggested in the comments are correct, please find a `dplyr` solution below:

```
merge(DT1, DT2, by = "id", all = TRUE) %>%
    filter(t2 >= start_time, t1 <= end_time) %>% 
    mutate(t1_adj = if_else(start_time > t1, start_time, t1),
           t2_adj = if_else(end_time < t2, end_time, t2),
           difftime = difftime(t2_adj, t1_adj, units = "secs")) %>% 
    group_by(id, start_time, end_time) %>% 
    summarize(durationFromDT2 = sum(difftime)) %>% 
    right_join(DT1) %>% 
    mutate(durationFromDT2 = coalesce(durationFromDT2, 0))
```

- `cross join` all records between each of the tables
- `filter` down the `cross join` to contain just those `DT2` times that have a timepoint *within* the `DT1` interval.
- `mutate` `_adj`usted columns to force the `t1` and `t2` times to remain constrained between `DT1` start and end timepoints, and then calculate the time intervals.
- `group` and `summarize` the durations by `DT1` records.
- To list all of the `NULL` records in the final result, `right_join` the `DT1` table back on again.
- `Replace` the `NA`s with 0's.

The result looks like this:

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 4
> # Groups:   id, start_time [5]
>      id          start_time            end_time durationFromDT2
>   <int>              <dttm>              <dttm>          <time>
> 1   604 2017-08-10 18:44:14 2017-08-10 19:33:17        180 secs
> 2   604 2017-08-10 20:38:20 2017-08-10 20:44:44        240 secs
> 3   604 2017-08-10 20:54:26 2017-08-10 20:58:48          0 secs
> 4   604 2017-08-10 21:35:50 2017-08-10 22:03:14        300 secs
> 5   604 2017-08-10 22:05:42 2017-08-10 22:17:12          0 secs
> ```

Reproducible (rectified) sample dataframes from the OP are below:

```
library(lubridate)
DT1 <- 
    read.table(text = "
                        id         start_date start_time  end_date   end_time
                        604        2017-08-10 18:44:14    2017-08-10 19:33:17
                        604        2017-08-10 20:38:20    2017-08-10 20:44:44
                        604        2017-08-10 20:54:26    2017-08-10 20:58:48
                        604        2017-08-10 21:35:50    2017-08-10 22:03:14
                        604        2017-08-10 22:05:42    2017-08-10 22:17:12
                      ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
    mutate(start_time = ymd_hms(paste(start_date, start_time)),
           end_time   = ymd_hms(paste(end_date, end_time))) %>% 
    select(-c(start_date, end_date))

DT2 <- 
    read.table(text = "
                         id         d1         t1          d2         t2
                         604        2017-08-10 18:40:14    2017-08-10 18:44:14
                         604        2017-08-10 18:44:14    2017-08-10 18:47:14
                         604        2017-08-10 19:44:14    2017-08-10 19:47:14
                         604        2017-08-10 20:30:14    2017-08-10 20:42:20
                         604        2017-08-10 21:44:14    2017-08-10 21:49:14
                         604        2017-08-10 22:44:14    2017-08-10 22:48:14
                      ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
    mutate(t1 = ymd_hms(paste(d1,t1)),
           t2 = ymd_hms(paste(d2,t2)),
           ) %>% 
    select(-c(d1, d2))
```

Comment: Sorry for late.the  end dates can fall on different dates.This has some problem when i run it in my whole data . The only line in DT2 for a day is like `3
2017-09-11 07:43:54
2017-09-11 07:47:26
` Then in my DT1 the record is like  `3
2017-09-11 18:44:14
2017-09-11 19:33:17
` But then the durationFromDT2 =1458 which twofold of the end_time-start_time.where I have no stretch in between.Could you advise on this? Is it because of i have records in different dates

Comment: This solution should work fine with different dates. I can only guess that you might need to ensure that you are filtering down to the overlaps only. Just run this line first and double check that you are screening out _all_ non overlapping periods: `merge(DT1, DT2, by = "id", all = TRUE) %>%
    filter(t2 >= start_time, t1 <= end_time)` You should not see that record above in the dataset. If the problem persists, could you add the records that you are having issues with to the sample data so that we can run those through too?

Comment: So sorry it was error in my DT2.Thanks a lot for the knowledge of the dplyr

Comment: My pleasure, and glad I could help